# How to read a file from within a the JAR. When both are present on the server

Tags: java, file, jasper-reports, jasperserver

This is the sample code which we were using:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("Data.xml"));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

So when using the same code on local we can get the path using `system.getProperties('user.dir')`.

Is there any way that we can get the path on JasperReports Server So that we can read the file. This particular code mentioned above is available in the JAR and xml is placed outside the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your file is on your system, why don't you use absolute path ?

```
new FileInputStream("/path/on/my/system/Data.xml")
```

Comment: For local machine absolute path served the problem.But for the server it was not working it was not picking the path of the file to perform the further operations.

Comment: Is your local env running the same OS than the server ?

Comment: yes.The file is on the JASPER server and need to call this file from a JAR.

Comment: I mean what's the os ?